# How can we control behavior of individual movie clips added randomly to stage from an array [as3]

Tags: actionscript-3

The code below adds a movie clip to the stage randomly from an array of movie clips. Once a movie clip is added to stage it moves horizontally on an x axis by echoing a corresponding sound clip. But my problem is, only the same sound clip is being played for any of the movie clips added on stage. The reason why its happening is of course because of the line:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new enemies[printArray[p]];
```

Can anyone please tell me how i can individually control the behavior of each movie clip that falls within "var mc". Instead of writing something like:

```
if(mc.x <= -100) { Enem1Timer.stop()} else if(mc.x <= 570){ Enem1Timer.start() }
```

is there a way to write like:

```
if(Enem1.x <= -100).....
```

Any help is most welcome. Thanx in advance.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var sound1:Letter1 = new Letter1();
var sound2:Letter2 = new Letter2();
var sound3:Letter3 = new Letter3();
var sound4:Letter4 = new Letter4();
var sound5:Letter5 = new Letter5();
var sound6:Letter6 = new Letter6();

var printArray:Array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var enemies:Array = [Enem1, Enem2, Enem3, Enem4, Enem5, Enem6];

for(var n:int = 0; n <= 6; n++)
{
var randNo:int = int(Math.random() * 6);
printArray.push(randNo);
}

var Enem1Timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);

Enem1Timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playA1);
function playA1(e:TimerEvent):void
{sound1.play();}

for(var p:int = 0; p < printArray.length; p++)
{
trace(printArray[p]);
var mc:MovieClip = new enemies[printArray[p]];

addChild(mc); 
mc.x = 600; mc.y = 200;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop)
function loop(e:Event){

if(mc.x <= -100) { Enem1Timer.stop()} else if(mc.x <= 570){ Enem1Timer.start() }

mc.x -= 3; 


}}
```

Comment: I would like to give credit to Baris Usakli for being able to benefit from his code posted under the Question "adding movieclips from random generated no in array"...the workable portion of this code come from his post - thnx Baris :)

Comment: The problem is the function inside the for loop. Closures inside loops use the value of the last itearation.

Comment: Baris yet another issue is, i am able to bring a movie clip to the stage only once. It does not continue as a repeated process. each time i have to hit ctrl+enter...is there a way that i can set a timer to a loop so that when something happens to the first movie clip on stage the next will follow randomly.

Answer (score 0):

if you mcs are already created in the array (not null) then you should remove "new" since you're accessing it, not creating it:

```
var mc:MovieClip = enemies[p] as MovieClip;
```

Comment: To expand on this answer I'll say that the OP should look into values and references to understand what it's going on there.

Comment: But mika, when i remove "new" i get the following error: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Enem1$ to flash.display. MovieClip.Also Pier what did u mean by "OP".

Comment: i'm not too sure about your code but you should also remove printArray and use an index instead. If you have loaded your array with objects, then you can access the first one for example by doing: var mc:MovieClip = enemies[0] as MovieClip;